# s-Domain Analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform

[image]

I've spent a really long time on this question but any approach I use gives me extremely messy solutions which make it impossible to convert the equations back into the time domain. 
This is what I've tried so far:

- I converted the capacitor into a resistor and a voltage source
- I then tried using superposition to find the individual components and add them up

The problem with this is that they lead to extremely messy equations, from which it's impossible to get time domain equations out of.

Comment: In the time domain it's a rather easy problem. Capacitor is initially charged at VA/2 and at t=0+ starts its discharge to -VA/2 with constant time R/2·C.

Comment: This doesn't use the method required by whoever wrote the problem, but try finding the Thevenin equivalent of the source with the two resistors for each of the switch positions.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the Thevnin equivalent across the capacitor can reduce the circuit as shown in figure.  Where the initial voltage across capacitor is Va/2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTmbc8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can find \$I_C\$ from this.

Now considering the circuit in the question, the current passing through the diagonal resistance \$I_2 = -(V_{A}+v_o)/R\$. Let \$I_1\$ be the current through horizontally placed resistor. Now,
$$I_1 = I_C + I_2$$
$$\frac{v_o}{R} = I_C - \frac{V_A+v_o}{R} \tag{a}$$

Since we have already found out \$I_C\$, \$v_o\$ can be calculated from (a).

Comment: But then there is no way to solve for $V_0$. Also, reducing it to the Thevenin equivalent would generate very messy equations since it's the s-Domain.

Comment: @dfg please see the edited answer. Hope that I haven't made any mistakes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not 100% steady with this, but (apparently and new to me) I find it entertaining to try to solve such problems. So anyway, I think I got some of the expressions and I hope it helps someone:

With \$V_{in}=V_o+V_c\$ I get:

$$
\frac{V_c}{V_{in}}(s) = \frac{\frac{1}{RC}}{\frac{2}{RC} + s}
$$

\$V_{in}(s)\$ is a unit step:
$$
V_{in}(s) = \frac{-2V_A}{s}
$$

$$
V_c(s) = \frac{\frac{-2V_A}{RC}}{s(\frac{2}{RC} + s)}
$$

Using a transform table, this form matches an asymptotic exponential and transforms in the time domain to:

$$
V_c(t) = V_c(t_0) - \frac{2V_A}{RC}\frac{RC}{2} ( 1 - \exp(-t\frac{2}{RC})) \\
V_c(t) = V_A/2 - V_A ( 1 - \exp(-t\frac{2}{RC}))
$$

As above we have, \$V_o(t)=V_{in}(t)-V_c(t)\$:

$$
V_o(t)= (V_A - 2 V_A u(t)) - (V_A/2 - V_A ( 1 - \exp(-t\frac{2}{RC})))
$$
Also \$I_c(s)\$ and \$I_c(t)\$ is now comparatively easy:

$$
I_c(s)=sCV_c(s) = \frac{\frac{-2V_A}{R}}{(\frac{2}{RC} + s)}
$$

$$
I_c(t) = 0 + \frac{-2V_A}{R} \exp(-t\frac{2}{RC}))
$$